# VBA Multicolumn Combox - get the value of second column when the first column is the bound column in the lists

Tags: excel, vba, forms, combobox

I have two User Forms (more actually, but these two are the ones I'm working with at the moment).

The first form is called "ExistingOrNewWelder" (I'll call it **Form A**).

The second form is called "InitialInfo_Form"(I'll call it **Form B**).

When the user clicks a button on the worksheet Form A is opened.  Initially, It looks Like this:

[image: Initial view of Form A]

When  the user selcts the radio button next to "Add a new WQTR for an existing welder" a Combobox appears.

[image: ComboBox shown in form with two lists]

When one of the items in the ComboBox is selected only the value of the bound column in the list is shown in the box.

[image: Shows ComboBox with only bound column data visible]

So where I'm struggling is that I want to be able to use both the name shown in the ComboBox and the ID number.  I want both pieces of information to appear in the subsequent Form B that is displayed when the user clicks OK.

[image: The next userform where I need the data to appear.]

In the image the word Foo represents the ID number from Form A and you will see that word in my current code which I am including below.

This first piece of code is for Form A.

```
Option Explicit
Dim newWelder As Boolean
Dim wqtr As Boolean
Public newWelderBoolValue As Boolean
Public welderIDSelected As String

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'varialbe fun
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim nameCell As range
    Dim box As control

    wqtr = False
    newWelder = False

    'Set Window size and position
    With Application
        .WindowState = xlMaximized
        Me.Top = .Top * 0.5
        Me.Left = .Left * 1.0015
        Zoom = Int((.Width * 0.85) / (Width * 0.85) * 60)
        Width = .Width * 0.28
        Height = .Height * 0.5
    End With

    'Activate the worksheet
    Worksheets("All Welders Data").range("A1").Activate

    'sort the data in the active sheet by the welder's name then by welder's ID number
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Add Key:=range("E3"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=range("B3"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SetRange ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Offset(1)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With

    'populate the combox from the active sheet (welder name in the
    'first column, welder ID number in the second column.
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        For Each nameCell In .range("E3:E" & lastRow)
            If nameCell.Value <> "" Then
                With Me.chooseWelderNameComboBox
                    .ColumnCount = 2
                    .AddItem nameCell.Value
                    .list(.ListCount - 1, 1) = nameCell.Offset(, -1).Value
                    'ComboBox now shows the values in column "E" and the values
                    'in coulmn "D" - in that order, as in  "Name" - "ID Number".
                    '(the reverse order of the columns in the worksheet.)
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub existingWelderOptionButton_Click()
    'display the welderName Combox when this radio button
    'is selected and set the switches(bools) for the Submit button.
    wqtr = True
    newWelder = False
    Me.chooseWelderLabel.Visible = True
    Me.chooseWelderNameComboBox.Visible = True
    Me.chooseWelderNameComboBox.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub AddNewWelderOptionButton_Click()
    'When this radio button is selected set
    'the switches(bools) for the Submit button.
    wqtr = False
    newWelder = True
End Sub

Private Sub chooseWelderNameComboBox_Change()
    welderIDSelected = "Foo"
End Sub
Private Sub submitButton_Click()
    'Based on the radio button selected, set
    'the Public newWelderBoolValue to either true or false
    'this is used by InitialInfo_Form.UserForm_Initialize
    If wqtr = True Then
        newWelderBoolValue = True
        InitialInfo_Form.Show
    Else
        newWelderBoolValue = newWelder
        InitialInfo_Form.Show
    End If
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

And then this next piece is only the portion of the code for Form B that is relevant to this question.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim welderSelected As Boolean
    Dim idSelected As String
    welderSelected = ExistingOrNewWelder.newWelderBoolValue
    idSelected = ExistingOrNewWelder.welderIDSelected

    'Set Window size and position
    With Application
        .WindowState = xlMaximized
        Me.Top = .Top * 0.5
        Me.Left = .Left * 1.0015
        Zoom = Int((.Width * 0.85) / (Width * 0.85) * 40)
        Width = .Width * 0.995
        Height = .Height * 0.992
    End With

    If welderSelected = True Then
        Me.welderNameText.Text = ExistingOrNewWelder.chooseWelderNameComboBox.Text
        Me.welderNameText.Enabled = False
        Me.welderIDComboBox.Value = idSelected
        Me.welderIDComboBox.Enabled = False
    End If

    welderIDComboBox.list = UserFormDropDownDataSheet.range("J2:J9000").Value

    weldingProcessComboBox.list = UserFormDropDownDataSheet.range("M2:M13").Value
    positionWeldedComboBox.list = UserFormDropDownDataSheet.range("O2:O14").Value
    testNumberComboBox.list = UserFormDropDownDataSheet.range("Q2:Q100").Value


End Sub
```

Comment: how about setting your welderIdselected to a global variable, that should make you able to call it from within a different sub on the same workbook. Or not set the sub to private, but to public.

Comment: welderIDSelected is already a public variable which is referenced by IDSelected in the second script.  What I'm having trouble figuring out is how to make welderIDSelected = "The welder Id number in the ComboBox list - which is the second column of data in the ComboBox."  @Luuklag - Every Welder has a unique matching ID number that goes with his name.  I have though about doing a column to column comparison in the worksheet but it seems to me that there should be a way to access that second column in the Combobox.  If Joe Bob is selected, his ID number is right there in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so, I found my answer.  Here is what I did to access the data in the unbound column of the multicolumn combobox.

In my code for Form A which I submitted as part of the question is this sub:

```
Private Sub chooseWelderNameComboBox_Change()
    welderIDSelected = "Foo"
End Sub
```

My question revolved around replacing "Foo" with whatever code would get me the data in the unbound column.  For example, if I chose "Allan Bailey" his name would be displayed in the ComboBox field but not the ID number associated with his name since that Id number is another column and only the name column is bound.  Here is the code that solved this:

```
Private Sub chooseWelderNameComboBox_Change()
    welderNameSelected = Me.chooseWelderNameComboBox.column(0)
    welderIDSelected = Me.chooseWelderNameComboBox.column(1)
End Sub
```

So you can see that I added the welderNameSelected variable but the trick is that the columns are indexed.  The bound column is index (0) and the second column is index (1).  It's as simple as that!  Both of the variables are Public and both of them are assigned a value when the user makes the selection. Both of them accessed by the subsequent script for Form B.

One thing to note is that I used Me.Hide to hide Form A instead of unloading it.  This way, it remains unloaded and i do not lose the values selected by the user in the combobox.